# cut and merge images in shader

Tags: shader, pixel-shader, opengl-es-3.0

my test image divide 4 part. | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
I need cut 1, 3 part and merge 1 + 3
and cut 2, 4 part and merge 2 + 4

final result  | 1 | 3 | 2 | 4 |

I was search shader example. but just find blend or mixing image.
please help me.

Comment: what have you tried, what kind of input can you provide, why do it in shader to begin with?

Comment: I need mix image data for my customer camera data, customer has two stereo camera, so one camera 1, 2 image and another camera 3, 4 image. customer's program merge two camera image, so output 1, 2, 3, 4 merge image. and I need shake or mix 1, 3 and 2,4 because this is stereo camera image.

Comment: self answer    vec2 position = gl_FragCoord.xy/Width; \n  L = (position.x < 0.5) ? L.rgb:L2.rgb;"